# Removing digits from list elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, text-analysis

I have a list of job titles (12,000 in total) formatted in this way:
`Career_List = ['1) ABLE SEAMAN', '2) ABRASIVE GRADER', '3) ABRASIVE GRINDER']`

How do I remove the numbers, parentheses, and spaces from the list elements so that I end up with this output:
    `Career_List_Updated = ['ABLE SEAMAN', 'ABRASIVE GRADER', 'ABRASIVE GRINDER']`

I know that I am unable to simply remove the first three characters because I have more than ten items in my list.

Comment: So you can just remove the first 3 characters? What does that have to do with how many items are in the list. Maybe split on the parens take the second element and `lstrip` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and the rest of the `strip` functions accept multiple characters as an argument.

```
Career_List_Updated =[career.lstrip('0123456789) ') for career in Career_List]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split each career at the first space; keep the rest of the line.

```
Career_List = ['1) ABLE SEAMAN', '2) ABRASIVE GRADER', '3) ABRASIVE GRINDER', '12000) ZEBRA CLEANER']
Career_List_Updated = []

for career in Career_List:
    job = career.split(' ', 1)
    Career_List_Updated.append(job[1])

print Career_List_Updated
```

Output:

```
['ABLE SEAMAN', 'ABRASIVE GRADER', 'ABRASIVE GRINDER', 'ZEBRA CLEANER']
```

---

One-line version:

```
Career_List_Updated = [career.split(' ', 1)[1] \
                       for career in Career_List]
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but what if there are no numbers in the string?

Comment: @ryugie: Then this isn't the problem OP posed for us.

Comment: I presume it's just format, but the "Output:" above the horizontal line appears to be a mis-copy on the second list element?

Comment: Thanks; my mouse button is going bad, I think; I get double-clicks.

Answer (score 0):

We want to find the first index that STOPS being a bad character and return the rest of the string, as follows.

```
def strip_bad_starting_characters_from_string(string):
    bad_chars = set(r"'0123456789 )") # set of characters we don't like
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char not in bad_chars
            # we are at first index past "noise" digits
            return string[i:]

career_list_updated = [strip_bad_starting_characters_from_string(string) for string in career_list]
```

Comment: This solution is overkill.

Comment: sure. i'm basically reinventing lstrip (which i forgot about)